# Link previews in Facebook Messenger bot using MS BotFramework

Tags: facebook-messenger, botframework

I'm using the node.js botFramework from Microsoft to create a Facebook Messenger bot.

Everything is working fine except when the bot sends the user a link. The link is shown in the chat window but FB does not generate any preview for it.

Is there a way to configure the app/bot or the message my app sends back so that the link preview is generated?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that Facebook supports automated link previews for URLs that are shared via bots.  You'll need to generate your own [HeroCard](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/attachments.html) for the url.